# Xamarin Forms: GetBackButton

Tags: xamarin, navigation, back

I have Xamarin App, in the app I have a page which I hide the navigation bar for design purposes. But I still want to show back button. What I could do is that I could make a back icon and put it on the layout and call `Navigation.PopAsync()` on image tab. However is there a way to get the designated back button from the app?

Comment: Are you using Android or iOS? You want your Bar to be invisible and the back arrow to appear, is that it?

Comment: I am using Xamarin Forms so both. Yes, exactly.